# Tried to install 18.04LTS and failed. Now can't get to BIOS/UEFI. Screen blank

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, uefi, bios

I bought a new  Win10 laptop (UEFI, Teclast F7). So of course I had to try and install (dual boot) 18.04 LTS right away. I setup a USB flashdrive and went to BIOS, disabled SecureBoot then boot from USB.

I chose Install Ubuntu from the menu and the installation process started as usual. Unfortunately the Ubuntu installation failed in the middle with error (forgot exactly) but it continued to GUI live session. I then run the Install Ubuntu from the LIve session, but I cancelled it when asked about setting password for the UEFI.

So I restarted the laptop again thinking about going to BIOS again because I remembered I need to turn off FastBooting also (which I didn't do the first time). But this time, I could't get to BIOS, pressing ESC key didn't work (Teclast logo also didn't come up) and it booted directly to Windows 10. I tried the Recovery menu from Windows and chose UEFI Firmware to fix and enter the BIOS several times, but I couldn't enter the BIOS, it just kept going straight to Windows.  The Teclast Logo also didn't show up as usual when booting.

Pressing different keys other than ESC also didn't work. Trying the Recovery menu several times also didn't work. But still, Windows was working fine. That is until Win10 updated itself. After it finished updating I shutdown (Shutdown and Update) the machine and went to sleep.

In the morning I tried again. But this time, the display remains blank. So all I got after pressing the power button is the LED lights up, numlock LED also lights up then off after a while. Windows seems to be booting because pressing some keys produces that familiar ding sounds. But the display is blank.

So now I'm stuck, I can not get to BIOS to boot from USB or reinstall Windows/Ubuntu, and can't do anything in Windows because the screen is blank.  So here's what I think. During the windows update, something went wrong with the display or display driver causing it to blank. And failed ubuntu installation somehow messed up the BIOS/UEFI preventing me to enter BIOS.

Sorry for the long post, but Can anyone help? How should I go about troubleshooting this mess?

TL;DR:

Failed installing Ubuntu. Can't go to BIOS. Can't do anything in Windows (screen blank/display driver problem??). I want to reinstall Win/Ubuntu but how?

Thanks in advance,

Regards,
T.Kart

Comment: Can you bring up your BIOS menu during POST (Power On Self Test)?

Comment: That's just it. I can't enter BIOS anymore. Even Teclast BIOS logo didn't show up. Pressing ESC key (or any other keys I tried: DEL, F1-F12) doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 enters into recovery mode after a few failed boot attempts. Just turn your pc on and off a few times, that is before it has time to boot completely.

Comment: Thanks, but no luck yet. Screen still blank. Tried more than 20 times. I'll keep trying.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it to work by opening the back cover and disconnecting the battery.